# Eigenvalues of bounded linear operator

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and $T$ be a bounded linear map from $X$ to $X$. Suppose that $a$ is an eigenvalue of $T^n$ for some postive integer $n$, Show that some $n$-th root of $a$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: If you don't want to use the spectral mapping theorem, just write $\prod_{i=1}^n(T-a_i)x=0$, where $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are the $n$th roots of $a$, and $x\in X$ is nonzero. Let $k\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ be maximal such that $\prod_{i=k}^n(T-a_i)x=0$. Now $a_k$ is an eigenvalue for $T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key fact here is the *Spectral Mapping Theorem*, which says that 
$$
\sigma(T^n)=\sigma(T)^n.
$$

Note that the theorem above is way more general: it shows that $\sigma(f(T))=f(\sigma(T))$ for any holomorphic (on $\sigma(T)$) function $f$.

As mentioned above by Ben, there is a straightforward way in the concrete case where $f(z)=z^n$.

If you let $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n$ be the $n^{\rm th}$  complex roots of $a$, then $(x-\omega_1)\cdots(x-\omega_n)=x^n-a$ (by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra). Then this equality can be also written for $T$:
$$\tag{*}
T^n-aI=(T-\omega_1I)\cdots(T-\omega_nI).
$$
Since $a$ is in the spectrum of $T^n$, we have that $T^n-aI$ is not invertible. Then at least one factor from the right hand side of $(*)$ is not invertible: this means that there exists at least one $k$ with $T-\omega_kI$ not invertible, and so $\omega_k$ is in the spectrum of $T$.

*Note that the argument above does not require "eigenvalue", and it works for all elements of the spectrum.*

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted.  Seems perfect.